# PhpStorm Angular subscribe - unresolved variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to develop an Angular app and I have an **"unresolved variable"** error at

> params.myid

Here is the code line:

```
 this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          const avalancheid = params.myid;
          });
```

There is no error if I change the type to **"any"** instead of **"Params"**

```
 this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
          const avalancheid = params.myid;
          });
```

Angular version: 4.2.4, PhpStorm version: 2017.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `Params` class doesn't contain the key `myid`, by using square brackets `params['myid']` you should be able to get the value as shown in the [docs](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html).

The reason it's crashing is because you're telling the TypeScript compiler "Hey, I'm expecting `Params`", at which point you then proceed to tell it to get a property named `myid` which the original `Params` class doesn't contain, hence the error.

Comment: I usually don't comment on someone's answer, so sorry for sounding rude, but you can use the `dot` notation to navigate a Type like `Params`, because it's not a `Class`, it's a `Type`. And when you try to link to the 'docs', please use the official docs. [**Here**](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#how-to-use) you can see an example using the params `dot`. The one you are referring to, is still on angular2, even though version 5 is out. :)

Answer (score 1):

There can be two issues here.

1. You are not importing `Params` from `@angular/router`:

like this:

```
import {Params} from "@angular/router";
```

You need this `Params` type, because it is defined as `[key: string]: any`, which allows for using the dot notation to navigate through the object.

2. Wrong typescript version:

This 'allowing' for using the dot nation is a relatively new feature though of `TypeScript`. So the other problem could be is that you are using an older version of TypeScript. Try updating to at least version `2.4.x`, to be able to use this feature, and while you are at it. See if you can update to the latest angular version as well. It's worth it.

If you are not willing to update, even though I strongly encourage you to do so, you can use the other notation to access the property:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  const avalancheid = params['myid'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! Sorry i forgot to write that Params was imported and I will update typescript!